# What can happen if you concurrently modify unprotected Java collections?

Tags: java, concurrency, jvm

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html

> **Note that this implementation is not synchronized.** If multiple threads access a linked list concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the list structurally, it must be synchronized externally.

What can happen if you don't? Can you crash the JVM, cause an exception or just produce inconsistent state?

What if there is one writer but concurrent reads happen unprotected? Can you still crash and mess up the state, or just produce a inconsistent read?

Is this implementation-specific, or does the spec guarantee a certain level of security and/or atomicity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nasty thing about thread safety is that errors can occur rarely and be difficult to reproduce. Java largely delegates the handling of Threads to the operating system, so the programmer is not in control of exactly how and when Threads get paused and switched by the OS when a number of tasks are running simultaneously. The frequency of kinds of errors observed can be different depending on whether the CPU is a single core or a dual or quad-core.

It is rare that concurrency errors will "crash the system," the more likely problem is inconsistent state. However, if you are iterating through a collection using an Iterator **while another Thread modifies the collection** then you will get a [ConcurrentModificationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html). For example:

```
 Set<String> words; //a field that can be accessed by other threads.
 // may throw ConcurrentModificationException
 public ArrayList<String> unsafeIteration()  {
   ArrayList<String> longWords = new ArrayList<>();
   for(String word : words) {
      if(word.length()>4)
        longWords.add(word);
   }
   return longWords ;
 }
```

The implementation of Iterator attempts to detect concurrent modifications of the collection it is iterating over, but this is just a best-effort attempt to "fail-fast". Having your program fail by throwing an exception is **much better** than having unpredictable behavior.
The javadocs make this disclaimer:

> Note that fail-fast behavior cannot be guaranteed as it is, generally
>   speaking, impossible to make any hard guarantees in the presence of
>   unsynchronized concurrent modification. Fail-fast operations throw
>   ConcurrentModificationException on a best-effort basis. Therefore, it
>   would be wrong to write a program that depended on this exception for
>   its correctness: ConcurrentModificationException should be used only
>   to detect bugs.

If we are simply reading data from a collection using `get` then we aren't going to see this exception, but we do run the risk of inconsistent state. There may be times when this isn't a problem that requires fixing. If only one thread writes to a field and it is not vital that all threads always see the most recent up-to-date value in that field, I think you should be fine as long as you stay clear of iterators.

Answer (score 1):

Using an unsynchronized collection in an multithreaded environment will cause problems like dirty reads (inconsistent data state) and [`ConcurrentModificationException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) (mostly when one thread has modified the contents of the collection while another was iterating through it).

Depending on your use case, this may cause your application to crash or [deadlock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock) (when one thread is shut down by the JVM due to the mentioned above, uncaught exception). Even worse, it may cause dodgy problems and erroneous results which may be difficult to trace. It will not crash the JVM itself, though.

I'd suggest taking a look at the [`java.util.concurrent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) package. You'll find a wide variety of thread-safe, efficient collections. Most of them have *weakly consistent* iterators, returning elements reflecting the state of the collection at some point at or since the creation of the iterator. This means they do not throw the `ConcurrentModificationException`, and may proceed concurrently with other operations.

For information regarding Java Memory Model and it's guarantees, please refer to [this](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html) (well worth reading!).

Answer (score 0):

You may not crash the application but your different threads will suffer from [DIRTY_READ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29#Dirty_reads_.28Uncommitted_Dependency.29) problems.

Answer (score 0):

The Javadoc of the root class of the collections framework, java.util.Collection, writes:

> It is up to each collection to determine its own synchronization policy. In the absence of a stronger guarantee by the implementation, undefined behavior may result from the invocation of any method on a collection that is being mutated by another thread; this includes direct invocations, passing the collection to a method that might perform invocations, and using an existing iterator to examine the collection.

"Undefined behavior" implies that the collection may do whatever it pleases, the entire javadoc of the collections framework is null and void. For instance, an element might still be present in the collection after being removed, or not present after being added. For instance, if Thread 1 adds to a HashMap and triggers a resize while Thread 2 inserts something, the insert from Thread 2 might be lost.

However, I would be greatly surprised if lack of synchronization could crash the JVM itself.